# Pinescript/TradingView: Set max pyramiding (multiple stacked entries of the same direction) but greater than 1

Tags: bots, pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

I'm writing a study (not a strategy) with alerts on the lower 5-min TF that allow for multiple entries (and a single close) of the same direction. Ideally, a max of 3 longs or 3 shorts before closing, or otherwise keep waiting for opposite entry or a close. (note I am not looking for code that limits to 1 entry/exit at a time). This is what I have thus far from what web research has suggested, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work (in my charts, plots appear very sparingly) -- I think I have pinpointed it to the security() function condition based on a higher TF data. When isolating the pyramiding by itself, it seems fine. When isolating the security function to check whether the data is being passed in, it plots fine. Please let me know if there is an alternative max-pyramiding logic or how to get it working with the higher TF data. Thanks in advance, any help appreciated.

```
// == ORDER CONDITIONS ==
longCond = security(tickerid,'60',someHFCond1)
shortCond = security(tickerid,'60',someHFCond2)

// Count your long short conditions for more control with Pyramiding

sectionLongs = 0
sectionLongs := nz(sectionLongs[1])

sectionShorts = 0
sectionShorts := nz(sectionShorts[1])

if longCond
    sectionLongs := sectionLongs + 1
    sectionShorts := 0

if shortCond
    sectionLongs := 0
    sectionShorts := sectionShorts + 1

// Pyramiding
pyrl = input(3,title="Max Pyramiding (stackable entries, default=3)",minval=1)
longCondition = longCond and sectionLongs <= pyrl 
shortCondition = shortCond and sectionShorts <= pyrl 

// Get the price of the last opened long or short
last_open_longCondition = na
last_open_shortCondition = na
last_open_longCondition := longCondition ? close : nz(last_open_longCondition[1])
last_open_shortCondition := shortCondition ? close : nz(last_open_shortCondition[1])

// Check if your last position was a long or a short
last_longCondition = na
last_shortCondition = na
last_longCondition := longCondition ? time : nz(last_longCondition[1])
last_shortCondition := shortCondition ? time : nz(last_shortCondition[1])

in_longCondition = last_longCondition > last_shortCondition
in_shortCondition = last_shortCondition > last_longCondition

// Take profit
Ltakeprofit = last_open_longCondition * (1+profittarget)
Stakeprofit = last_open_shortCondition * (1-profittarget)
long_tp = high[1] > Ltakeprofit and longCondition == 0 and in_longCondition  == 1 and not longCondition[1]
short_tp = low[1] < Stakeprofit and shortCondition == 0 and in_shortCondition == 1 and not shortCondition[1]

// Create a single close for all the different closing conditions.
long_close = long_tp or long_sl ? 1 : 0
short_close = short_tp or short_sl ? 1 : 0

// Get the time of the last close
last_long_close = na
last_long_close := long_close ? time : nz(last_long_close[1])
last_short_close = na
last_short_close := short_close ? time : nz(last_short_close[1])

// Alerts & Signals
bton(b) => b ? 1 : 0
plotshape(longCondition , title="buy alert", color=green, textcolor=green, transp=0, 
          style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.small,text="LONG",offset=0)
plotshape(shortCondition, title="sell alert", color=red, textcolor=red, transp=0, 
          style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, size=size.small,text="SHORT",offset=0)
plotshape(long_tp and last_longCondition > nz(last_long_close[1]), text ="Close", title="Take Profit Long", style=shape.triangledown, 
   location=location.abovebar, color = green, size=size.tiny, editable = false, transp = 0,offset=0) 
plotshape(short_tp and last_shortCondition > nz(last_short_close[1]) , text ="Cover", title="Take Profit Short", style=shape.triangleup, 
   location=location.belowbar, color = red, size=size.tiny, editable = false, transp = 0,offset=0)
```

Comment: Note: This is working in conjunction with the "security()" function to for the long and short condition to take place only when a higher timeframe indicator is valid. When removing that higher TF check, then I think the pyramiding works. But when removing the pyramiding cap (the above code) and letting it have unlimited stacking, the security() higher tf check works. So I'm quite stuck.

Answer (score 0):

This shows your pyramiding control working just fine:

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
// == ORDER CONDITIONS ==
barUp = close > open
longCond = barUp and barUp[1]
shortCond = not barUp and not barUp[1]

// Count your long short conditions for more control with Pyramiding

sectionLongs = 0
sectionLongs := nz(sectionLongs[1])

sectionShorts = 0
sectionShorts := nz(sectionShorts[1])

if longCond
    sectionLongs := sectionLongs + 1
    sectionShorts := 0
    label.new(bar_index, low - tr, tostring(sectionLongs, "▲\n#"), xloc.bar_index, yloc.price, color.green, label.style_none, color.green, size.large)

if shortCond
    sectionLongs := 0
    sectionShorts := sectionShorts + 1
    label.new(bar_index, na, tostring(sectionShorts, "#\n▼"), xloc.bar_index, yloc.abovebar, color.maroon, label.style_none, color.maroon, size.large)

// Pyramiding
pyrl = input(3,title="Max Pyramiding (stackable entries, default=3)",minval=1)
longCondition = longCond and sectionLongs <= pyrl 
shortCondition = shortCond and sectionShorts <= pyrl 

bgcolor(longCondition ? color.lime : shortCondition ? color.red : na)
plotchar(sectionLongs, "sectionLongs", "", location.top)
plotchar(sectionShorts, "sectionShorts", "", location.top)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time! Yes, I isolated the pyramiding and it works fine. I also isolated the security ticker for the higher TF data and it works fine. But once combined, it doesn't work. To be specific, the security condition is only long when the macd remains positive (50ema > 200ema) on the 1h TF and only short when the macd remains negative (50ema < 200ema) on the 1h TF. Once the security and the pyramiding elements are combined, the plots are not working as expected. Any ideas?

Comment: Hadn't seen your comment before answering. As for the higher TF thing, without code that compiles it's very difficult to help. If you don't want or it's too complicated to share code here, use the same technique we used to plot markers that will allow you to validate your elementary conditions and then, if the compound conditions you are building with them correspond with their states.